# Best practices for regression when using seasonal data?

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, arima, interaction

I have a variable $y$ that I would like to model using a set of independent variables $X$. Both $y$ and $X$ are monthly measurements (~10 years in total) and appear to be subject to seasonal variability. Theory and initial analysis suggest that multicollinearity and interaction effects are also present in my $X$.

Right now all I want to do is to explore the relationship between $y$ and the variables in $X$, but in the future, I probably will need to forecast future values of $y$. Initially, I just used the data as is in an OLS fit, only standardising them to z-scores because my theory suggested that I didn't need an intercept.

My colleagues said that this approach was naive and that there would be no way of differentiating genuine relationships from the seasonal cycle. To that end, I performed a seasonal adjustment on each variable by fitting and removing 12 dummy variables. However, I now find that my seasonally adjusted $X$ and $y$ fit very poorly compared to my previous model ($R^2$ with holdout data drops from 0.7 to 0.3).

Is there any way to effectively deal with seasonal variation without directly estimating & removing the seasonality in this way? Because of the seasonal cycle, I think that this could be described as an autoregressive process, so I guess I could try adding lagged variables but I am unsure of what to do next. What I don't understand is the following:

1. If all my variables have a similar seasonal cycle (i.e. peak in summer, the trough in winter, though exact maxima & minima vary within 1-3 months), do I need to explicitly account for seasonality at all?
2. If my fits with seasonally adjusted data are so poor, does this mean that my data is unusable and/or my theory is incorrect?
3. As an autoregressive process, should I include both lagged $y$ and $X$ terms in my fits, as they all have seasonal variability? Most examples I've read online seem to be concerned with lags in $y$ only.
4. For this problem should I be using $ARIMA$, $ARIMAX$, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions.

> If all my variables have a similar seasonal cycle (i.e. peak in
> summer, trough in winter, though exact maxima & minima vary within 1-3
> months), do I need to explicitly account for seasonality at all?

Not necessarily, no.

Consider a simple hypothetical data generating process where "variables have a similar seasonal cycle".
Suppose $X_t$ follows a seasonal AR process,
$$
(1 - \phi L^{12}) X_t = \epsilon_t, \;\; |\phi|<1
$$
This is an SARIMA(0,0,0)$\times$(1,0,0)$_{12}$ process. What happens this January $X_t$ depends on what happened previous January $X_{t-12}$ plus a random shock $\epsilon_t$.
Suppose $y_t = \beta X_t + u_t$, where $u_t$ is independent of $\epsilon_t$.

If you regress $y_t$ on $X_t$, your OLS $\hat{\beta}$ estimates $\beta$ just fine. ($\hat{\beta}$ is consistent if $E[u_t X_t] = 0$, and this condition holds here).

In fact, if you take the residuals $\hat{\epsilon}_t$ and $\hat{u}_t$ obtained from de-seasonalizing $X_t$ and $y_t$ respectively, and regress $\hat{u}_t$ on $\hat{\epsilon}_t$,
the $R^2$ will be much smaller than the $R^2$ from just regressing $y_t$ on $X_t$. The $\hat{\beta}$ from the residuals regression would be close to zero in large sample.

This would be similar to the $R^2$ result you're describing. In your case, seasonality is modeled additively via seasonal dummies while SARMA models multiplicative seasonality. But the same discussion would apply verbatim.

> If my fits with seasonally adjusted data are so poor, does this mean
> that my data is unusable and/or my theory is incorrect?

No. As the above example shows, if the seasonality of the dependent variable $y_t$ derives from that of $X_t$, de-seasonalizing removes the correlation between the two---the opposite of what you're trying to do.

> As an autoregressive process, should I include both lagged y and X
> terms in my fits, as they all have seasonal variability? Most examples
> I've read online seem to be concerned with lags in y only.

Check whether the residuals from regressing $y_t$ on $X_t$ is white---in particular whether it has serial correlation.
Presence of serial correlation would indicate you're missing lagged $y_t$ variables in the regression.

If the true model is
$$
y_t = \beta X_t + \gamma y_{t-1} + u_t
$$
and $y_{t-1}$ is omitted from your regression, the residuals would have serial correlation.
Adding the lag $y_{t-1}$ would improve forecast (subject to usual considerations such as model stability/in-sample fit vs out-of-sample forecast/etc).

> For this problem should I be using ARIMA, ARIMAX, or something else
> entirely?

The model
$$
y_t = \beta X_t + \gamma y_{t-1} + u_t
$$
is already one example of ARMAX.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael!